# Location services

Tags: iphone

I have in plenty of Core Location based apps that before triggering the code for location services an alert pop up and warns user that the app is going to use their current location. Is this a in-built feature of Core Location or we need to implement it before calling API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's built-in. As of iOS4 you can modify the text body for this alert specifically for your app.

Follow this link
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125

and find `purpose` property in the doc.

Comment: Wow...that is definitely obscure.  Thank you for finding that!  I skipped right over that when I read that page.

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in. When you try to call core location methods, if the user hasn't allowed your app to do so before, the OS will automatically pop an alert.